# Rule to check if a date value is a specific day of the week

Tags: rules, datetime

I want to set a rule which checks a date of format "2014-09-24 08:43:39" is a Monday using the data comparison rule. I have tried to manipulate the data selector for the date using the ":custom:N" format however data comparison wont accept it.
I'm trying to do it from within the rules module as my PHP is a bit limited.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had myself many troubles with Rules and dates too. There are [several open issues in Rules about dates](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rules?text=date&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All). So the solution that I offer is very cumbersome and to be honest I don't like it too, but it seems to be the only thing to work. Improvements are of course welcome. Maybe there is also some module which I miss.

Note that this is about Rules ver. 7.x-2.7. The solution involves both some PHP code and components.

So the first issue at hand is that it seems Rules cannot change the format of a date variable in a data comparison, or to properly convert the data type.

Therefore I am using a rule to get the weekday from the variable, then pass it to a component as a variable (integer). In that component I can easily do a data comparison for the interger and procedd with any actions.

In order to get the weekday, I create an action "Add a variable". In there, I use some PHP code in order to directly get the week day. Here is the second issue: Rules do not seem to properly expose the variables in PHP. Therefore I specify the type of the variable as text, and then I specify the value using one of the replacement patterns in the direct input mode (otherwise a date will not be available in the data selection mode). Now we have the date as a string in a variable. Let name the variable `variable_added`.

The second action is to "Set a data value". In there, you specify:

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime(DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d/m/Y - H:i', $variable_added));
return $datetime->format('w');
?>
```

We create a DateTime object from a hard-coded format. This has to be the Drupal long date format which Rules seem to use for their date formatting. There got to be an API function that returns the current format which atm I miss, and so we have it hard coded to get us going. Replace this with your installation's custom format from `/admin/config/regional/date-time`, also consult [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Then we use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/datetime.format) to get the day number.

So now we have the day number as a string. The third action would be to convert the above variable to an integer, and then in a fourth action you would call the rules component passing on the converted variable along with any other variables you would need.

Appendix: My test case rule export.

```
{ "rules_test_date" : {
    "LABEL" : "Test date",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php" ],
    "ON" : { "cron" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[site:current-date]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "variable_added" : "Added variable" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "variable-added" ],
          "value" : "\u003C?php\r\n$datetime = new DateTime(DateTime::createFromFormat(\u0027D, d\/m\/Y - H:i\u0027, $variable_added));\r\nreturn $datetime-\u003Eformat(\u0027w\u0027);\r\n?\u003E"
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : [ "variable-added" ] } },
      { "data_convert" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : [ "variable-added" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "conversion_result" : "Conversion result" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Wtower for your great work, really appreciate it. I can follow you up until the "set a data value" part, In the rule, I add an action "set a data value" with Selected data: variable-added, and in the value box, I paste the php code. I think this is where I am going wrong as if I do a message on the site with the "variable-added" included, I get the php code printed out.

Comment: If I print out the "variable-added" before applying the "set data value" the date format shown has the 3 letter weekday format at the start, if that helps. Thanks Adrian

Comment: You're welcome, Adrian. Can you verify that the PHP module is enabled in the list of modules?

Comment: If you mean the PHP filter module, no it wasn't, now it is and I get:"<br /> <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in <b>C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\My Web Sites\acquia-drupal7\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> " as a result.

Comment: It seems that this error comes from the PHP code in the action, but I can't see something wrong with the code. It runs ok to me. Can you import the test rule and give it a shot by running cron?

Comment: I tried importing the rule by copy and paste into rule import, but it came up with "Import failed.
Unable to parse the pasted export." Is there another module I need to enable? Learning on the run here and loving it!

Comment: You're right, there were two } missing at the end in the rule export. I also changed the PHP code with something better, but you have to replace the date format with the format you are using.

Comment: Now getting an error : Exception: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in DateTime->__construct() (line 2 of C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\My Web Sites\acquia-drupal7\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code). This is odd as the variable is definitely passed as text so it should be in a string?

Comment: Ok I've had some success, after removing the "new DateTime" from the php code,and swapped the m/ and d/ around to match the date format on my computer, I was able to get it to work! however, it returns nothing (no message) for a sunday (day 7)? I have tried fiddling with the round-up/down in convert data type to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm very glad. Let's avoid extended discussions in comments, probably this is a separate matter. I have no idea why but you can take a look to variables in PHP using `debug($variable);`. If it doesn't show immediately (depends on the rule event), check your log report. If the answer was useful please do not forget to mark it accepted! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this works for your specific case, but for me this little module is quite useful in a similar context as it provides for a "check what day it is" Rules condition (and Event):

https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday

> The module also provides a "Day of the week is a" Rules condition, to
>   further restrict actions to being run on specific day(s) of the week,
>   on working days only, or at weekends only.