# How to implement responsive social sharing button with counters?

Tags: theming

I'm looking to implement some social sharing buttons on my website.

Requirements are

- responsive
- counters

I like the looks of the [Ridiculously Responsive Social Share Buttons](https://www.drupal.org/project/rrssb) module, but they don't have counters.

Any ideas about how to implement this in a Drupal, maybe using some jQuery library?

Comment: you need jQuery for the responsive part. Bootstrap library perhaps? Another option would be to custom code it, but since you're asking for a library I take it you're not familiar enough with jQuery to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of this following

1) [Social Share Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_share_counter)

> This module is clearly inspired by the share buttons used by Mashable.
>
> This module gives the share counts for only Facebook,Twitter and more
>   which has some excellent features in more elegant manner. If you have
>   a website, then you definitely need this module.

2) [Social Share statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_share_statistics)

> This module is developed to track the share statistics of social media
>   clicks. So when a registered drupal user shares any content to social
>   media, this module saves the uid, nid and the share count for
>   FB/twitter/GPlus in the database for the record.
>
> There is a 'Shares' tab on the user profile page where the user can
>   get the list of content shared on different social networks (facebook,
>   twitter).
>
> This module only tracks shares that are made using the share buttons
>   that the module provides. If you share the nodes with some other
>   mechanism (say directly copy paste the link to Facebook, Twitter, etc.
>   or use some other module), those actions / shares do not count.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Social Stats

Have a look at the [Social Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_stats) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This is a statistics module. It provides data from various social media sites. The data which is saved per node. It includes data from:
>
> - Facebook : likes count, shares count, comments count & total count.
> - Twitter : tweets count.
> - LinkedIn : share count.
> - Google Plus : plus one count, share count & total count
> - Total Share Count : total across all available social networks
>
> It does not actually provide sharing widgets for the social networking sites. They have to be added manually, or using other modules. List of the modules recommended to use along with Social Stats are:
>
> - [Service links](https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links).
> - [AddThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis).

## Option 2: Rules

A completely different approach is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, as detailed in my answer to "[How to show the number of times a page has been shared by all services total?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183655/how-to-show-the-number-of-times-a-page-has-been-shared-by-all-services-total/183664#183664)".