# How to share only a particular link in a node using social media,instead of complete node?

Tags: nodes

Using [**user referral**](https://www.drupal.org/project/referral) module i was able to generate referral link.
After this i enabled **[social media](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia)** module in order to share the particular link to other people whom i would be referring.

While testing this,i came to know that instead of link,entire node is being shared.

Can anyone tell me  an idea as how to share only the link,apart from getting the entire node being shared

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using an alternative module (instead of the [Social Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia) module), you can get this to work for at least **Facebook** and **Twitter** by using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module instead, combined with these modules:

- [Facebook rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_rules) (for Facebook, of course ...).
- [Twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) (for Twitter, of course ...).

For (way) more details on that, refer to my answer to "[How to post the node link in social networking if node is published?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183136/how-to-post-the-node-link-in-social-networking-if-node-is-published/183198#183198)", which also explains what the options are (that I'm aware of) for **Google+**.